# Remove the leading apostrophe from dataframe column python

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, google-sheets

I have a dataframe that I upload to google sheets using python script. Specifically, my goal is to get the sum of one column filtered by the date range within this google sheets spreadsheet using query.
In a spreadsheet, the date column which is *`orderDate`* has an leading apostrophe to it, if you click on it *(see attached img)*. I tried all the methods like strip(), replace(), with lambda function, and with regex, but none of them worked. In the case of `orderLineQuantity.amount` column it worked, as it was an integer. Here is the code in python.

```
df_orders['orderDate']=df_orders['orderDate'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df_orders['orderDate'] = df_orders['orderDate'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("'", ""))

df_orders['orderLineQuantity.amount'] = df_orders['orderLineQuantity.amount'].str.replace(r"[\"\',]", '')
df_orders['orderLineQuantity.amount'] = df_orders['orderLineQuantity.amount'].astype(int)
```

Here is my query, but it is throwing me the ***#N/A Error: Query completed with an empty output.***

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("link_to_the_Spreadsheet", "ORDERS!A2:J"), "SELECT SUM(Col6) WHERE Col1 >= date '2023-03-01' AND Col1 <= date '2023-03-05' LABEL SUM(Col6) ''")`

I think the problem is in the `orderDate` column's data type? It has date and time, but I want to filter only by date. And I'm thinking if I manage to remove the apostrophe sign from the `orderDate` column, google sheets will recognize it as a date, not text.
[image]

Please help me with this issue, I've tried a lot of things, and now I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You specifically convert the column to string in your second line.  Google (like Excel) SHOWS you an apostrophe if the cell is a string.  The apostrophe is clearly not in the data you are creating.  If you don't want it to be a string, then don't do that conversion.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for clarifying. I removed the second line and updating the below line by adding `value_input_option='USER_ENTERED' ` helped. 
`worksheet.update([df_orders.columns.values.tolist()] + df_orders.values.tolist(), value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')`

Comment: Actually, you create a column of data type string in your *first* line of code in the example (btw. you can simplify with [pd.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)). The second line effectively does nothing. Besides the displayed apostrophe, it can in fact be helpful to keep date/time formatted as text, i.e. when you don't want Excel etc. to mess around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['orderdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['orderdate'])
```

or

```
df['orderdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['orderdate'], format="'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```